# Setting the calendar value using viewDate function in Tempus Dominus

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

What I am trying to do is set the month and year from an event calendar to Tempus Dominus datepicker. So on the main page is a big calendar, the user may change the month from November to December, and the create a new event in December.

Once the user clicks the button to enter a new event, I want to set the datepicker to that month. Per the docs on the page I access the functions with:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(FUNCTION)
```

To set the `viewDate` I need to put the date in `()` `viewDate('11/21/2018')`
putting it together (I have tried a few different ways it should look something like:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(viewDate('11/21/2018'))
```

I have put `viewDate` in single quotes, tried `viewDate:` and a few others, with no luck. I currently have it wired to a button and hard coded the date like above for testing.

What is it that I am not understanding or doing wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that the right way of calling [`viewDate`](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Functions/#viewdate) function is:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('viewDate', <value>)
```

where `<value>` is a string (compliant with [`format`](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#format) option), moment or Date value.

Anyway, I fear that the current version (`5.1.2`) of Tempus Dominus datetimepicker has a bug/issue and the `viewDate` is not notified to the component view.

If you need you can use `date` instead of `viewDate` to change component's value.

Here a live sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

$('#btnViewDate').click(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('viewDate', moment('11/21/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') );
});

$('#btnDate').click(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('date', moment('11/21/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnViewDate">
        Set viewDate
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDate">
        Set date
      </button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The viewdate issue is in the older versions to, going back to 5.0.1 Alpha, if I go older then i need to switch to BS3 from BS4, and a bit too deep to do that. I have tried to create the picker on the fly, and set default to what I need no luck. Also tried it through destroy with no luck. Just need to find time to finish my picker.

Comment: I agree with you, going back to bootstrap 3 it's too much. I've opened [this](https://github.com/tempusdominus/core/issues/13) issue on github to keep track of the problem, hopefully the mantainer of the library will fix it.

Comment: Using 'date' worked for me with Tempus Dominus 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of  [tempus-dominus](https://getdatepicker.com/6/options/)  they are using class now ex :

> options: object of the configurations

```
new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('datetimepicker1'),options);
```

So to change the value you should use setValue function

> instance: instance of TempusDominus class

`instance.setValue("2023-04-04")`

they are more function to deal with tempusDominus datetimepicker like :

> getviewDate : Returns a moment variable with the currently
>
> setviewDate : opposit of getviewDate
>
> updateOptions : Update the picker options. If `reset` is provide
> `options` will be merged with DefaultOptions instead.
> ex :

```
let  options = {
                        display: {
                            components: {
                                calendar: true,
                                date: true,
                                month: true,
                                year: true,
                                decades: true,
                                clock: true,
                                hours: true,
                                minutes: true,
                                seconds: true
                            }
                        },
                        localization: {
                            format: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'
                        }
                    };




instance.updateOptions(options);
```

more function [TempusDominus repository](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus)